# Does setting a variable to 'undefined' actually free the space?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for an explicit way to be sure that JavaScript garbage collector will do its job pretty soon.

So does setting a variable to `undefined` is a guarantee?

```
var foo = "something";
// do stuff with foo

foo = undefined;
// awake the Garbage Collector interest to him
```

Comment: keep in mind that variable is still in memory even when it is set as undefined and will take space.

Comment: The best way for the GC to collect this is to make it go out of scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In theory no, it won't be gargage collected. There's still a reference in memory to this variable. The fact that it contains an undefined value is irrelevant.

Imagine RAM like a giant storage of boxes. Those boxes are shared between different companies (UPS, FedEX, etc). Each box has an address, and each company tells some central application "hey, the box at this address is being used by me". So even if you empty or undefine the box, there's still a 1:1 connection between let's say UPS and that box. In the same way your JS interpreter tells your operating system ("hey, the memory location at xxx is being used by me, don't assign it to anybody else").

The fact that it contains an undefined value doesn't free this memory location. Your operating system does not know nor care what's in that memory location, he knows it's assigned to your JS interpreter, and your JS interpreter linked it to your variable *foo*.

You shouldn't be troubling yourself with garbage collection in JS anyway. As long as you create your variables in the right places and don't flood the global object (but even then I doubt you're gonna have much problems) every variable is going to be garbage collected automatically as soon as it can't be used.

Comment: So the best practice still to declare `ephemere` variables in the scope of function or blocks and to put `persistent` variable in the global scope ?

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin `persistent variable in the global scope` Generally speaking you should'nt need to use global scope at all.

Comment: Ok I got it the variable still alive, however the space is free rigth ? since `undefined` does not take that much space ? rigth ?

Comment: The best practice is always to declare variables in the narrowest scope you can. That way your JS engine knows when to garbage collect them.

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin, you don't know nor have control on how much space in memory undefined gets, your interpreter handles that for you, and does an amazing job at it. No the space is NOT free. If you have a reference to a memory location the space is used regardless of what's inside it.

Imagine memory like houses. The city council assigned you a house on a certain street. Regardless of the fact you're currently home or not this space is already assigned.